# How I can read the contents of text file using google drive api v3

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried to use Get(). I was able to read/update the file metadata but don't know how to get the file contents. From my googling I know I have to identify alt=media but I don't know how. Could anybody give a full example.

Answer (score 0):

- To retrieve the contents of a Gogle document like Google Sheets, Google Docs etc. you can use the Sheets API, Docs API etc. respectively
- **To retrieve the contents of a non-Google file on your Google Drive, like e.g. a text file - you cannot do it directly**
- Instead, you need to donwload the file to your local Drive
- For this, when using the method [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get), specify `alt=media` as you already know
- However, this will not directly give you the file contents, but rather request a download of the contents from the server
- In the next step you need to write this downloaded content to a file on your local machine
- The [Guide for downloading files stored on Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive) provide samples of how to do so in Java, Python and Node.js